# Java/Android - Plus minus button on a calculator

Tags: java, android

This is not a **duplicate**. Unlike other `StackOverflow` questions, I don't want to display the result of the expression and then add a `minus` or `plus` sign. I want to turn the entire expression into `negative` or `positive` when pressed.

*For example*:

```
-(5*8+7/7)
```

or when `+/-` pressed again:

```
5*8+7/7
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
negative = !negative;

if (negative == true)
{
    expression = "-(" + expression + ")";
}
else
{
    expression = "+(" + expression + ")";
}
```

While this does work fine in terms of calculation, I am finding trouble figuring out how to create an intelligent way such that `+(` and `-(` do not keep getting appended to the expression.

Comment: Check if the first symbol is a `+` or `-` and then append?

Comment: The +( ... ) part is wrong in any case. It doesn't do anything (it should be a minus also in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the positive/negative state in a boolean and add the -(...) part when rendering. Otherwise you can match the beginning and and to match -( resp. ) and simply remove it. However, that will miss the simple case of -5. To cover all corners you will write quite some code. I would keep it as a separate state if possible.

Edit: Just want to add that the "proper" solution would be to parse the string and build a tree representing the expression (an AST) and detect if the outermost operator is a unary minus and simply remove it (or add it if it is not there), then check if the next operator are the parentheses and remove them (if you didn't just add the minus), and finally regenerate the string. But all this require quite some more work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use two textfield include the expression, like [textfield A][expression][textfield B], and textfield A and textfield B can not be input from user, just only change when user press negative/positive button.

View will like:

-(  5*8+7/7  )

or

  5*8+7/7

Think this can help you.